# Mix HQL and Criteria API in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to mix HQL and the Criteria API?

I have a `String` that contains a where condition in HQL and a `Criteria` that is already built and got from somewhere else. I wonder if I can add the where condition `String` to `Criteria.add()`. The where condition could be multiple conditions "and-ed"/"or-ed" together.

Can I do this without parsing the where condition `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Restriction.sqlRestriction](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29)(String sql).

Comment: This would work for a SQL criterion but not necessarily for a HQL criterion. I'd like to just add in a HQL string criterion instead.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)