# Add Criterions and Orders to HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to add `Criterion`s and `Order`s to an HQL statement?

For example, given HQL

```
from Category c where c.name like 'Laptop%'
```

Can I add the following?

```
Order.asc("name")
Restrictions.eq("enabled", "Y")
```

The reason for this awkward design is because the HQL comes from a configuration file whereas the `Order` and the `Restrictions` come from a web form that allows the user to specify filters and sort the result.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is [`Mix HQL and Criteria API in Hibernate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135851/mix-hql-and-criteria-api-in-hibernate)

Comment: Actually, I posted that question. The difference is that I need to specify a full HQL statement and add Criterions and Orders to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use named parameters, e.g.:

```
from Category c where c.name like 'Laptop%' and enabled = :enabled
```

and

```
query.setParameter("enabled", "Y");
```